# Find the IP of an internet host using its MAC adress only

Tags: network-programming, ip-address, vpn, mac-address

I would like to avoid VPN for permanent connection to a remote host, I would like to replace the static IP address with the MAC address, and using the MAC to find the IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The MAC is used for local routing, not global routing. A MAC on a remote network is hidden by a gateway on the remote side. You can't even tell *which* gateway is doing that. It's even possible that the IP address doesn't have a MAC address behind it. This was the case for instance with dial-up lines; there would be a phone number behind it.

This explains why there's no API for this.